# Getting data by index from the C++ model in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

How do you get the data from your model (sub-classed from `QAbstractItemModel`) outside of the delegate using QML?

I tried it like this:

```
Identities {
    id: identities_model
}
...
console.log(identities_model[0].email)
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

My `data()` method is defined like this:

```
QVariant Identities::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    int row_num;
    row_num=index.row();
    if (role==EmailRole) {
        QList <QString> qlist;
        qlist=identities_map.keys();
        if (row_num>=qlist.size()) return (QVariant());
        return QVariant(qlist.at(row_num));
    }
    if (role==PasswordRole) {
        QList <QString> qlist;
        qlist=identities_map.keys();
        if (row_num>=qlist.size()) return (QVariant());
        Identity *identity;
        identity=identities_map.value(qlist.at(row_num));
        return QVariant(identity->password());
    }
    if (role==Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return(QVariant());
    }
}
```

I tried to debug (put some breakpoints) but couldn't intercept any call to `Identities::data()` or `Identities::index()` towards my model from QML. How should I access data in my model outside of the delegate? (specific row, specific role) When I use delegates, my model works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement `Identity * at(int index)` slot or invokable function for the model. Then `identities_model.at(0).email` should work.

The roles are not at play here, as your `Identity` is a `QObject` derived, it should implement them as properties in order to be used in QML. The roles are only for the view delegate. Had it not been a `QObject` derived, you could use `Q_GADGET` to generate meta info for the type to make it accessible from QML.

The `[]` operator would work had your model been a JS array. Also, JS would not complain about your model not having a `[]` operator, it would simply give you an `undefined` because it is undefined. The same way it would be for something like this:

```
  var v = 3
  console.log(v[0])
```

JS doesn't support operator overloading, nor will it support any operators, implemented on the C++ side. Functions only.

Comment: Isn't the usual name `get` rather then `at`?  At least the `ListModel` has no `at`, only a `get` function.

Comment: thanks a lot! using my own method to get the data is a good solution.

Comment: @derM - you definitely would want a `get()` if you plan on having a `set()`. If you don't it doesn't really matter as long as it gets the job done. Item at index 0 sounds about right to me.